# How to dynamic chart js with laravel inertia and vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, chart.js, inertiajs

I want to make this chart dynamic using Laravel and Vue.js. I want to display the data from a table based on the month and income type. I want the payments to be displayed based on the month and income type.
How can dynamic this chart.

Here is my controller code:

```
    public function index(): Response
{
    $accountings = Accounting::select('month_id', 'kind_id', 'payment')
        ->with(['month', 'kind'])
        ->get();
    $chartData = $this->prepareChartData($accountings);
    // dd($chartData);
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
        'chartData' => json_encode($chartData),
    ]);
}

private function prepareChartData($accountings)
{
    $months = [];
    $kinds = [];
    $data = [];

    foreach ($accountings as $accounting) {
        $month = $accounting->month->name;
        $kind = $accounting->kind->name;

        if (!in_array($month, $months)) {
            $months[] = $month;
        }

        if (!in_array($kind, $kinds)) {
            $kinds[] = $kind;
        }

        $data[$month][$kind] = $accounting->payment;
    }

    $datasets = [];

    foreach ($kinds as $kind) {
        $dataset = [
            'label' => $kind,
            'data' => [],
        ];

        foreach ($months as $month) {
            $dataset['data'][] = $data[$month][$kind] ?? 0;
        }

        $datasets[] = $dataset;
    }

    return [
        'labels' => $months,
        'datasets' => $datasets,
    ];
}
```

Here is my component code:

```
<script>
 import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
 import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, 
 CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

 ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, 
 LinearScale)

export default {
name: 'BarChart',
components: { Bar },
data() {
    return {
        chartData: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'data-1',
                    data: [40, 20, 12]
                 },
                { label: 'data-2',
                    data: [40, 20, 12]
                 }
            ],
        },
        chartOptions: {
            responsive: true
        }
    }
}
```

}

this is my database:

```
Schema::create('accountings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('blockNum');
        $table->integer('kind_id')->unsigned(); //نوع در آمد مثلا برق یا آب 
        $table->integer('month_id')->unsigned();//نام های ماه را از جدول months میگیرد 
        $table->string('price');
        $table->string('payment');
        $table->string('unpay');
        $table->date('pay_date'); // تغییر نوع ستون به date
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```